# MYSQL - COUNT performed on limited number of rows in a Joined table

Tags: mysql, join, limit

I'd like to join two tables (resources and empath_task_history) then count the number of categories ("safety_level" on a limited number of rows.

Below is what I've tried, but I'm getting the following error: 
"ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias"

```
SELECT safety_level,COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT * FROM empath_tasks_history LIMIT 10)
LEFT OUTER JOIN resources 
ON resources.resource_oid = empath_tasks_history.item_oid
GROUP BY safety_level;
```

I'd appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: `(SELECT * FROM empath_tasks_history LIMIT 10)` needs an alias. try `(SELECT * FROM empath_tasks_history LIMIT 10) a`

Answer (score 0):

So the final correct code was:

```
SELECT safety_level,COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT * FROM empath_tasks_history LIMIT 10) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN resources 
ON resources.resource_oid = a.item_oid
GROUP BY safety_level;
```

Thank you Fabricator.